# One Lambda is working, one isn't. (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm trying to make an advanced baseball metric calculator. Can anyone explain why the lambda in "wobaentry" is returning nonetypes when calling the "wOBA" function. I have a set of functions that I modelled this segment after and it's working perfectly. What am I overlooking? Any insight would be greatly appreciate

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

def wobaentry():
    wobainput= Tk()
    L4 = Label(wobainput, text = "wOBA", fg = "red", font = "Times").grid(row=1, column=1)
    L5 = Label(wobainput, text ="Walks").grid(row=2, column=1)
    L6 = Label(wobainput, text ="Singles").grid(row=3, column=1)
    L7 = Label(wobainput, text ="Doubles").grid(row=4, column=1)
    L8 = Label(wobainput, text ="Triples").grid(row=5, column=1)
    L9 = Label(wobainput, text ="Home Runs").grid(row=6, column=1)
    L10 = Label(wobainput, text ="At bats").grid(row=7, column=1)
    L11 =Label(wobainput, text ="Sacrifice flies").grid(row=8, column=1)
    L12 = Label(wobainput, text ="Intentional Walks").grid(row=9, column=1)
    L14 = Label(wobainput, text ="Hit By Pitch").grid(row=10, column=1)
    E4= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=2, column=2)
    E5= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=3, column=2)
    E6= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=4, column=2)
    E7= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=5, column=2)
    E8= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=6, column=2)
    E9= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=7, column=2)
    E10= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=8, column=2)
    E11= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=9, column=2)
    E13= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=10, column=2)
    B5= Button(wobainput, text= "Calculate wOBA", command = lambda: wOBA(E4, E5, E6, E7, E8, E9, E10, E11, E13) )
    B5.grid(row=15, column=2)

def wOBA(E4, E5, E6, E7, E8, E9, E10, E11, E13):
    wOBAoutput = Tk()
    L13 = Label (wOBAoutput, text = "wOBA", fg="black", font = "times")
    L13.grid (row=1, column = 1)
    E12 = Entry(wOBAoutput, bd=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
    bb = float(E4.get())
    hbp = float(E13.get())
    singles = float(E5.get())
    doubles = float(E6.get())
    triple = float(E7.get())
    hr = float(E8.get())
    ab = float(E9.get())
    sf = float(E10.get())
    ibb = float(E11.get())
    ubb = bb - ibb
    woba = float(((ubb * .69) + (.720 * hbp) + (.884 * singles) + (1.261 * doubles) + (1.601 * triple) + (2.072 * hr)) / (ab + bb - ibb + sf + hbp))
    E12.insert(0, str(woba))
    E12['bg']='grey'
```

This is the set that is working:

```
def pythagentry():
    pythaginput = Tk()
    L0 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Expected Wins", fg="black", font = "Times")
    L0.grid(row=1, column=1)
    L1 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Runs Scored", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    L2 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Runs Allowed", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    L3 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Season Length", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    E1 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E1.grid (row=2, column=2)
    E2 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E2.grid (row=3, column=2)
    E3 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E3.grid (row=4, column=2)
    B4 = Button (pythaginput,text='Calculate Pythagorean Wins', command = lambda: pythag(E1, E2, E3) )
    B4.grid (row=5, column=2)

def pythag(E1, E2, E3):
    pythagoutput = Tk()
    L4=Label(pythagoutput,text="Expected Wins:",fg="red")
    L4.grid (row =1, column =1)
    E5=Entry(pythagoutput, bd=5)
    E5.grid(row=4,column=1)
    runsscored= float(E1.get())
    runsallowed= float(E2.get())
    lengthseason= float(E3.get())
    ratio = runsscored / runsallowed
    winpct = pow (ratio, 2) / (pow(ratio, 2) + 1)
    expectedwins = lengthseason * winpct
    E5.insert(0, str(expectedwins))
    E5['bg']='grey'
```

Comment: You speak about 2 lambdas but I see only one : `lambda: wOBA(E4, E5, E6, E7, E8, E9, E10, E11, E13)`

Comment: Yes I referenced two in my writing, one working one not. I added it

Comment: widget.grid() retuns None.
change `E4= Entry(wobainput, width= 60).grid(row=2, column=2)` to 2 lines

Comment: That was the issue, I had no idea. I get into the habbit of just tacking .grid at the end when I'm typing a lot of code

Comment: All of the geometry manager methods (`pack`, `grid`, `place`) return `None`, so it's always best to separate declaration and placement: `foo = Entry(); foo.pack()`